# Understanding Parallelization

Tags: multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

I made a system parallel and did some testing on it but I can't understand what is happening. Each column is a matrix calculation and the time it took to calculate it. Why is it that increasing the number of threads for CPUs reaches a threshold?

When I have 4 CPUs and 4, 8, 16 Threads, why doesn't the system speed up any further? Could it be the cost of read/writing for each CPU being so expensive that the effectiveness tapers off?

```
**2 CPUs**

1 Thread    0.72 s  10.31 s 34.77 s 42.07 s 120.93 s
2 Threads   0.48 s  7.88 s  22.63 s 28.40 s 82.81 s
4 Threads   0.50 s  7.12 s  24.22 s 28.68 s 80.78 s
8 Threads   0.49 s  6.92 s  24.14 s 28.80 s 80.88 s
16 Threads  0.57 s  6.89 s  24.23 s 29.68 s 81.35 s

**4 CPUs**

1 Thread    0.71 s  10.30 s 34.95 s 43.07 s 120.93 s
2 Threads   0.48 s  7.06 s  22.78 s 28.33 s 82.81 s
4 Threads   0.49 s  5.47 s  20.37 s 21.82 s 67.45 s
8 Threads   0.40 s  5.16 s  17.83 s 21.84 s 61.71 s
16 Threads  0.46 s  5.20 s  17.75 s 22.19 s 65.37 s
```

Comment: May we look at your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Every problem would reach a threshold. Here is what you need to consider:

1. time to spawn threads
2. communication overhead
3. memory bandwidth and cores competing to access the memory to read/write
4. how many memory banks do you have
5. how you wrote the code to achieve maximum cache hit
6. did you try to hide memory latency?

MIC and GPU are efficient coprocessors that you can consider if you like.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of problem. The most simple case is known as an embarrassingly parallel problem - you have N decoupled tasks that require no intercommunication. These tasks then scale linearly as you add up to N processors.

Many real world tasks aren't like that though - they require intercommunication with other elements of the system. Message passing requires both parallel processes to synchronise, which means time is wasted in the interim. There are a variety of ways of doing this, but pretty fundamentally - any time this communication needs to happen, you 'waste' efficiency and scaling.

[Ahmdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) covers this - the principle is that you will never get linear scaling of parallel performance by increasing concurrency, but the more you can decouple your task, the better you get.

Perhaps counterintuitively - you can actually get more performance by 'wasting time' repeating calculations, because the relative expense and overhead of Inter Process Communications (IPC) is more than the time spent duplicating work.

So the long and short of it is - it depends on your algorithm. Minimise IPC and you'll get better scalability.